# VS 2017 - NuGet Manager does not add reference

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I´m trying to add System.Management.Automation to my project.
My project uses the .Net framework 4.5.

In my last project, I was able to add this reference easily by the NuGet manager console where I just had to type "Install Package" + the package name.

This time I tried the same but without any success.
I also already tried the following steps but still no success:

- Reinstall the package by "Update-Package"
- Delete the NuGet package so VS will reinstall it
- Clear Nuget Manager Cache
- Change the .Net framework
- Clear project

I don´t have any other options left so hopefully someone of you can help me.

Comment: Did you try through package manager gui? Sometimes it will not show the package as reference if the package is for newer versions of framework than the project. It is also weird that it does not throw any warnings or errors when installing the package.

Comment: Can not you **download** the package, or can not you **add it** to a `csproj` file?